# Navigation controller title not showing up?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

So when I have my `OptionsViewController` as the `rootViewController` in the `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`...

```
let rootVC = OptionsViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
        navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

...setting the title of the `OptionViewController` works if I do this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    title = "Route Options"
```

[image]

But when I push `OptionsViewController` onto the navigation stack the title doesn't show up.

I.e. if I start w/ a different view as the `rootViewController` in `AppDelegate`:

```
 let rootVC = HomeViewController()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And in `HomeViewController` I push my `OptionViewController` like this:

```
    let optionsVC = OptionsViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(optionsVC, animated: true)
```

The title does not show up!

[image]

The only way I've managed for the title to show up is by doing (in `OptionViewController`)

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Route Options"
```

But it shows up as the back button rather than in the middle, which is not what I want.

[image]

If anyone could tell me how I could set the title so that it is on the middle of the navigation bar when it is pushed onto the navigationController stack that would be great!

## Code

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let rootVC = HomeViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
        let barAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        barAppearance.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
        barAppearance.tintColor = UIColor.white
        barAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

**HomeViewController.swift**

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, DestinationDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let optionsVC = OptionsViewController()
            self.definesPresentationContext = false //else going to try and present optionVC on homeVC when in optionVC
            navigationController?.pushViewController(optionsVC, animated: true)
        }
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**OptionsViewController.swift**

```
class OptionsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,
    DestinationDelegate, SearchBarCancelDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,
    CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.title = "Route Options"
    }
```

Comment: When you push `OptionsViewController` from `HomeViewController`, are you still using `self.title = "Route Options"` in the `viewDidLoad` of `OptionsViewController`?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I set the `title` in `viewDidLoad` of the `OptionsViewController`

Comment: Just as a test, comment out the lines that mess with the nav bar's colors.

Comment: Yep still doesn't work when I transition from `HomeVC` to `OptionsVC`, but it does show up when I transition from `OptionsVC` to `RouteDetailVC` and back to `HomeVC` to `OptionsVC`

Answer (score 9):

You need to set the navigationItem.title to desired value. If you want an image you set navigationItem.titleView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Your title here"
 }
```

Comment: set it on the view controller, not the navigation controller

Comment: that's what I did `class OptionsViewController:UIViewController{      override func viewDidLoad() { self.navigationItem.title = "Your title here"
}`

Comment: FYI - `self.title = "Some Title"` works just as well as `self.navigationItem.title = "Some Title"`

Answer (score 6):

For others coming here based on the title, don't forget to set your ViewController class in IB to the appropriate Swift file.

After doing that I was able to set the title without a problem using

```
self.navigationItem.title = "my title"
```

or

```
self.title = "my title"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it:

In `HomeViewController`:

```
let optionsVC = OptionsViewController()
navigationController?.viewControllers = [optionsVC]
```

And in your `OptionsViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationItem.title = "Your Title"
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. When I transition from `HomeViewController` to `OptionsViewController` the title is still blank it doesn't even show a back button now. However, when I transition from `OptionsViewController` to `RouteDetailViewController` (which gets pushed onto the `NavigationController`) and then transition back the title shows up. This is very strange

Answer (score 3):

first you need to set `UINavigationBar` color and text color . 
 try this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
let barAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    barAppearance.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
    barAppearance.tintColor = UIColor.white
    barAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

if you want to remove the string after backbutton 
add these too

```
let barItemAppearace = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
    barItemAppearace.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
```

And just set your title in `viewDidLoad()` or

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.title = "Your Title"

}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. When I transition from `HomeViewController` to `OptionsViewController` the title is still blank. However, when I transition from `OptionsViewController` to `RouteDetailViewController` (which gets pushed onto the NavigationController) and then transition back the title shows up.

Comment: i have been using this for more than 4 apps its working . confirm that your UIViewController is embed in a uinavigation controller

Comment: I've added that I have right now. For some reason, you're code makes it so that my `OptionsVC` shows up under the nav bar. Also the nav bar title does not show up until I transition from `OptionVC` to `RouteVC` back to `HomeVC` and then to `OptionVC`, so it's the same glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below line to set the title for navigation item

```
self.title = "Title 1"
```

Comment: if you need to set up the title for navigation item. You need to explicitly tell the navigation item.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Objective-C** I also had the problem that it didn't show me the title but going to the next Scene the title appeared next to the back button.

I don't really know why, but I solved it by programming the relative ViewController of that Scene in **Swift** instead of **Objective-C**.

After that, it was enough to use the command:

```
self.title = "My Title"
```

and so I was able to write what I want programmatically, using if-statement or other methodologies.

Maybe this could be useful to someone who has this problem with **Objective-C**.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is initialisation `navigationItem.title` by string containing any **printable** symbols in `viewDidLoad` function. String like `""` or `"  "` will not worked.
Like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "."
    }
```

Then code `navigationItem.title = "Any string"` will work well anywhere in your ViewController.

***This bag was fixed in iOs 16.2***